# Fields for selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that has a fields for helper in it and I need to get the value of each of those fields in my rails application.

```
<%= form.fields_for :expenses do |expense| %>
      <%= render 'expense_fields', f: expense %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add field", form, :expenses %>
```

**expense_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :expense_name %>
        <%= f.select(:expense_name, options_for_select([['Hotel', 'hotel'], 
        ['Registration', 'registration'], 
        ['Meals', 'meals'], 
        ['Flight', 'flight'], 
        ['Mileage', 'mileage'],
        ['Car Rental', 'car rental'],
        ['Parking', 'parking'],
        ['Traning', 'training']],), { include_blank: true }, id: 'principal_selection', class: 'form-control') %> 
    </div>
  </div>
    <% if current_user.admin? || current_user.principal? || current_user.super? %>
      <div class="col-md-3">
    <% else %>
      <div class="col-md-7">
    <% end %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :expense_cost %>
        <%= f.number_field :cost, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Cost', step: :any %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% if current_user.principal? || current_user.admin? || current_user.super? %>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :payment_type %>
      <%= f.select(:payment_type, options_for_select([['Out of pocket', 'Out of Pocket'], ['Corporate Card', 'Corporate Card'], ['PO', 'PO']], selected: "Half Day"), { include_blank: false }, class: 'form-control') %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have checked around the rails guides and was not able to find a way to directly extract the value for each fields for in the select helper. Anybody have any ideas?

I tried doing `selected: "#{@expense.expense_name}"` but get a nil error because @expense is not defined. So I went into the edit method in the pdforms controller and tried this:

```
def edit
@expenses = @pdform.expenses
end
```

That yielded no result so I tried this:

```
def edit
@expenses = @pdform.expenses
@expenses.each do |ex| 
  @expense = ex
end
```

But that just returned one value in the form when it is being edited. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have a suspicion that your `f` variable is perhaps not what you think it is. Could you perhaps add a `<% Rails.logger.info f %>` in your `expense_fields.html.erb` file so you can see what you are dealing with? I'd expect `selected: f.expense_name` or `f.object.expense_name` should work in this scenario.

Comment: In your partial, your only reference to these nested expenses is the local variable `f` that references the current `expense` in a for loop.

Comment: So `f.object.expense_name` did in fact work. When I did the logger it returned `true` so i'm not sure what that is about. After seeing that it makes sense as to what object is referencing since it is passed in the fields for render method.

Comment: Great! For clarity I've added that as the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `fields_for`, each item that you then reference is available as `.object` on each `field` instance. So in this case, use:

```
f.select(selected: f.object.expense_name  ...
```